# Multiple For Each in Terraform

Tags: azure, foreach, scripting, terraform

I am trying to deploy multiple for_each in terraform. I have two variables:

1. `variable "VirtualNetworks"` is for two VLANS, deployed in two different locations.
2. `variable "VirtualMachines"` is for six VM's, 3 in each of the VLANS.

Following are variable types:

```
variable "VirtualNetworks" {
  type = list(object({
    VirtualNetworksName     = string
    VirtualNetworksLocation = string
    SubnetName              = string
    NGSName                 = string
  }))...}

variable "VirtualMachines" {
  type = list(object({
    OS          = string
    location    = string
    hostname    = string
    interfaceid = string
    size        = string
    environment = string
    publisher   = string
    offer       = string
    sku         = string
    version     = string
  }))...}
```

The issue is when I am trying to assign 6 network interfaces dynamically, I don't know how to. Following is the way I have tried.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf_example_nic" {

  for_each = { for i, v in var.VirtualMachines : i => v }
  # for_each = { for j, w in var.VirtualNetworks : j => w }

  name                = each.value.interfaceid
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.tf_example_rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name      = "internal"
    subnet_id = each.key != "0||1||2" ? azurerm_subnet.tf_example_subnet[0].id : azurerm_subnet.tf_example_subnet[1].id
    # subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.tf_example_subnet[each.key].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.tf_example_public_ip[each.key].id
  }

}
```

Is there a way I can try and make this dynamic. Any assistance will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about dynamic blocks: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks?

Comment: read about nested for_each here https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2021/08/19/nested-for-each-with-terraform/

Comment: Thanks @TaniaPetsouka let me try this and if I can achieve, I will share solution